# How to style react bootstrap carousel with next js?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, jsx, react-bootstrap, next.js

I am new to next.js and I would like to remove the gradient around the arrows to the left and right of the react bootstrap carousel.
I have tried inline CSS for the carousel and I am using styled-components for the rest of my components.

Comment: Please, include the code in your question. I suggest you to create a sandbox to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation of react-bootstrap package says that it uses Bootstrap v3 styles:

[React-Bootstrap currently targets Bootstrap v3. To use React-Bootstrap, include the CSS for Bootstrap v3 instead of Bootstrap v4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HztYy.png)

If we [look through bootstrap.css file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6331), we can see that carousel controls have .carousel-control.left and .carousel-control.right classnames for left and right button respectively. So we can use styled-components nesting feature to specify CarouselWrapper component which will override default controls background styles (you should definitely use other class style properties from bootstrap source here, I omitted them for clarity).

```
 const CarouselWrapper = styled.div`
   .carousel-control.left,
   .carousel-control.right {
     background: none;
   }
 `;
```

It is a bit "monkey-patching" approach but I could not find another way to pass custom styles for carousel controls background.

Check full proof-of-concept code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pypkzo5kz0